# How to resolve "CryptoUnavailableError: No crypto library available" in Conda on OS X?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-oauth, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to access a Google App Spreadsheet from IPython running a Python 3.5 kernel using an OAUTH2 service account, leveraging the Google API Python client, but got stuck with the "CryptoUnavailableError: No crypto library available" error.

I followed Google's documentation (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts) and also consulted various articles on stack**overflow**. In a conda virtual environment I successfully installed the following libraries:

- pip install google-api-python-client --upgrade
- conda install cryptography
- conda install pyopenssl

However, the following code fragment still results in the CryptoUnavailableError:

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

with open("mykey.p12", 'rb') as f:
  private_key = f.read()

client_email = 'myaccount@myapplication.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
scope = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key, scope)
```

- OS X version: 10.10.5
- conda version: 3.18.9
- jupyter version: 4.0.6
- Python version: 3.5.1

Anyone managed to get encryption working for Python 3.5 in Conda on OS X?

Comment: This might be a masked import error deeper in the import stack. Usually a sign that some native component is missing or miscompiled. You can trace it down by walking through it source code import line deeper and deeper until you get the actual error.

Comment: Might be related: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2138#issuecomment-153537522

Comment: My Homebrew workaround line   `env CRYPTOGRAPHY_OSX_NO_LINK_FLAGS=1 LDFLAGS="$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib/libssl.a $(brew --prefix openssl)/lib/libcrypto.a" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" pip install cryptography`

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: it might be related to the fact that conda which downloads/installs binaries specific to the platform into virtual environments makes use of relative paths instead of absolut paths. I was/am hoping for a solution on "conda-level", as I'm not too proficient in Python development/debugging

Comment: Please post more of your error traceback.  That will help in determining where this error is happening.